# Does MySQL exectution plan depend on available indexes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, index, index-tuning

Does MySQL choose an execution plan for a given query taking into account what indexes are available, or does it first choose an execution plan and then uses indexes if they are available?

*Motivation:* I want to decide which indexes would be useful. I have a number of typical queries. So I can imagine two possible strategies:

- If the plans do not depend on available indexes: see the execution plans of those queries and add indexes useful for these plans, or
- If the plans depend on available indexes: add all possible indexes (a lot!), see the plans for the queries, and remove unused indexes.

My DB is not very large, so I can afford playing with indexes. I currently use InnoDB, but I can switch to MyISAM or another if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL's optimizer looks only at what indexes are available.

There is an exception in 5.6:  If you have a subqueries such as
`FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ...`, there are no indexes on the temporary tables that are created.  This used to lead to terrible performance.  Now, the optimizer will try out various indexes, and create the best one for the tmp table.  I suspect it only looks for single-column indexes, not "compound" indexes

InnoDB is getting the most attention these days.  MyISAM does not have any tricks up its sleeve.

Try out my [Cookbook for creating the best index, given a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  It may save you some false starts.

Comment: I've looked at your cookbook, looks very promising. Why don't you convert it in a real program? Say, online: the user pastes several queries on your webpage and gets a list of recommended indexes (maybe with some additional constraints). Or don't you know of such a tool? Or doesn't MySQL do it? Looks pretty trivial: make EXPLAIN believe that there are all possible indexes (a finite number anyway) and see how it *would* act, then actually make those indexes. Can't be done in MySQL? Is it a good idea to make all indexes, run EXPLAIN, and delete those unused?

Comment: Yeah, I am pondering a web page.  I haven't found a parser for SELECTs, so I have to write that first.  I can't use EXPLAIN without having the table and sample data.  Even then, the distribution of the data can make a difference.  And then come different versions, with different syntax, etc.

Comment: There are tools that try to discover which indexes are "unused".  They are flawed because they look at which indexes are used over some period of time.  But they can miss that important job that runs once a week and must have this otherwise unused index.

Comment: If my UI tries to connect to _your_ database to do then EXPLAIN, then there are all sorts of firewall, connection, security, etc issues.  I consider that to be a non-starter.  I _could_ "give" you a stored procedure that you have to install and run.  That's what I do with pivot and lat/lng.  (See the links at the bottom of that blog.)

Comment: And thanks for the favorable comment about my cookbook.  My ego an I appreciate it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have been struggling to build a UI that analyzes your `VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL STATUS` (that you paste in).  It has about 200 formulas, plus crude advice.  I gladly run it for people, but I have to edit the output too much.  So, it would be embarassing to put it online.

Comment: About algorithm, I really meant something simple -- just an embodiment of your algorithm, to be applied automatically instead of manually, and with all sorts of understood inaccuracies as to the specific data distribution etc. Hopefully something simple. Providing an actual stored procedure would be even greater and I'd be happy to have one, but I did not ask for so complicated work :-)

Comment: In another question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95868/finiding-missing-index-details-in-mysql I say that I've just discovered MS SQL Server has functionality to tell you which index it **would** use if it existed. That's exactly what I need. Can we do it in MySQL other that build millions of indexes and run `EXPLAIN` to see which ones are unused?

Comment: And yes, it's obvious that an "unused" thing like Christmas decorations can be something important but used rarely, so granted, one would use common sense before dropping unused indexes.

Comment: JOINs are messy, especially if the user has redundant parentheses.  A "covering" index needs to parse the entire SELECT fully.  An extra desirable thing is to "fix" this common mistake:  `WHERE DATE(dt) = '2015-03-20' by turning it into a range on dt.  I'm afraid I won't stop at "simple".  And I haven't even gotten to limits on the size (bytes wide) of an index.

Comment: I have addressed thousands of questions about performance.  Building the 'right' index may be the most common thing that novices are in need of.  It wasn't until after I gave a 3-hour lecture ("all about indexing") for the third time that all the pieces of the cookbook gelled in my mind.  Your nudging me may finally make the automatic UI a reality.

Comment: Great! So one of the most common problems will be finally solved! Perhaps nudging you will prove to be my main contribution in computer science :-)) Seriously: 99% of world problems are caused by trivial things we novices miss, even if trivial for experts like you, busy with infinitely more complex things. How many people in the world don't get the change count right while experts are concerned with the remaining Hilbert problems?

Comment: Ah.  A fan club.  ;)