# Finding missing_index_details in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, index

MS SQL Server apparently can tell you what indexes would be useful for your query. Is there anything similar in MySQL?

[This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/tune-your-indexing-strategy-with-sql-server-dmvs/) (scroll to "Find missing indexes") says that in Microsoft SQL Server you can use `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` etc. to see what indexes would be useful for a given query, which largely renders deciding what indexes to make a trivial task.

In contrast, with MySQL I only know of `EXPLAIN` as a way to see whether an index that you already have is used for your query, but not what index would be used it you had it. This renders choosing what indexes to have a trial and error procedure.

Or, you may be tempted to create all possible indexes (millions!) and then use EXPLAIN to see which ones are actually used. But this seems to be too much work?

The question is whether we have a similar functionality in MySQL: to make EXPLAIN *assume* you have any index it might wish, and tell you which one it *would* use if it existed?

Comment: The answer and comments in [Does MySQL execution plan depend on available indexes?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95854/does-mysql-exectution-plan-depend-on-available-indexes) address much of this question.

Comment: Right :-) I just wanted to have it as a separate question for those who might need it.